# Can a SQL Azure admin user create other admins?

Tags: sql, azure

I have a client using a SQL Azure database.

They want to be able to manage the creation and removal of users.

I am the server admin, and set up the initial Azure subscription.

I have created an "Admin" user for them, as follows:

```
--On master
CREATE LOGIN TestAdmin
WITH PASSWORD = 'ThePassword'

CREATE USER TestAdmin 
FOR LOGIN TestAdmin

ALTER ROLE loginmanager
ADD MEMBER TestAdmin

--On UserDB
CREATE USER TestAdmin
FOR LOGIN TestAdmin

--Add to db_AccessAdmin
--so the admin can add or remove access to the database 

ALTER ROLE db_accessadmin   
ADD MEMBER TestAdmin

--For the admin, use the built-in roles
ALTER ROLE db_datareader
ADD MEMBER TestAdmin

ALTER ROLE db_datawriter
ADD MEMBER TestAdmin

GRANT EXECUTE
TO TestAdmin

--And allow the admin to make structural changes if required:
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin
ADD MEMBER TestAdmin

--Allow Admin to manage role membership
ALTER ROLE db_securityadmin
ADD MEMBER TestAdmin
```

I have created code which the new admin can execute via the application, to allow this admin to create a new "standard" user like this:

```
--ON User Database:
--To create new (non-admin) user 
CREATE USER TestUser WITH PASSWORD='P@ssw0rd!'
ALTER ROLE DBUser ADD MEMBER TestUser
```

Note: The role called DBUser is a role I've created to be similar to a combination of db_datareader and db_datawriter, so that we're not using these built-in roles other than for the admin, and can grant more precise permissions as required.

This works nicely, and the new user can do all they need to do.

However, they want the new admin to be able to create new admins.... I know that this risks becoming a security nightmare with admins begetting admins and so on for ever more, but I want to know if this is possible but inadvisable, or not possible.

The new admin essentially needs to run the same code as I've run above to create the TestAdmin.

They can log into Master, and run this:

```
CREATE LOGIN TestAdminsAdmin
WITH PASSWORD = 'ThePassword'
```

But the next line to execute, also on Master, would be this:

```
CREATE USER TestAdminsAdmin 
FOR LOGIN TestAdminsAdmin
```

This fails, as "User does not have permission to perform this action.".

Is there a permission I can grant the New Admin to allow them to do this on Master, or is that a "by design" security restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure SQL database, the master database just has  two roles `dbmanager` and `loginmanager`. One role has permissions to  create and delete databases. The other role has permissions to create and delete logins in the master database. So if we want to creat user in the master database, we must use the admin account. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15#special-roles-for--and-azure-synapse) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage#create-additional-logins-and-users-having-administrative-permissions).
[image]

Comment: Hmmm... That's what I thought. Okay. So, given that I'm the only person able to set up another user in Master, that makes me the only real Admin (server admin). Which is fine, until I get hit by a bus. Thanks for your help.